# jquery autocomplete showing id and not label

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm using jquery's autocomplete function and it's working just fine except that when I select something from the drop down list, the input field get populated with the value and not the label.

My code is as follows:

```
 <?php
   $query =     mysql_query("SELECT users.* FROM users JOIN peers ON peers.peer = users.user_id WHERE peers.user_id = '".$_SESSION['id']."'")or  die(mysql_error());
   $count   =   mysql_num_rows($query);
   $i   =   0;

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
   {
       $first[$i]   =   $row['first_name'];
       $last[$i]    =   $row['last_name'];
       $user_id[$i] = $row['user_id'];

       $i++;
   }

$data = "";

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    if($i != ($count-1))
    {
        $data .= '{ value: '.$user_id[$i].', label: "'.$first[$i].' '.$last[$i].'" }, ';
    } else
    {
        $data .= '{ value: '.$user_id[$i].', label: "'.$first[$i].' '.$last[$i].'" }';
    }
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#auto").autocomplete({ 
    source: data,
    select: function(event, ui)
    {
        var id = ui.item.value;
        var name = ui.item.label;
    }
  });
  </script>

  <input type="text" value="Enter a connection's name" id="auto" />
```

Comment: maybe you just need to swap `value` and `label`...?

Comment: Yeah, but then the autocomplete function will load the values instead of the labels.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The default behavior of the select event is to update the input with ui.item.value. This code runs after your event handler.

Simply return false or call event.preventDefault() to prevent this from occurring. Try this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#auto").autocomplete({ 
        source: data,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
           var id = ui.item.value;
           var name = ui.item.label;
           $("#auto").val(name);
           return false;
        },
        focus: function(event, ui){
          return false;
        }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either try putting the `label` first in the array before `value` or review this code from jQuery's documentation on [.autocomplete() with custom results](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var projects = [
        {
            value: "jquery",
            label: "jQuery",
            desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
            icon: "jquery_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            value: "jquery-ui",
            label: "jQuery UI",
            desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
            icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png"
        },
        {
            value: "sizzlejs",
            label: "Sizzle JS",
            desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
            icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png"
        }
    ];

    $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: projects,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
            $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "images/" + ui.item.icon );

            return false;
        }
    })
    .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append( "<a>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
</script>



<div class="demo">
<div id="project-label">Select a project (type "j" for a start):</div>
<img id="project-icon" src="/demos/autocomplete/images/transparent_1x1.png"  class="ui-state-default"//>
<input id="project"/>
<input type="hidden" id="project-id"/>
<p id="project-description"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of the autocomplete select event is to populate the input field with value instead of the text

But you can use the following code to update the input field with the text on selection as well as also on scrolling down the options.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#auto").autocomplete({ 
        source: data,
        select: function(event, ui)
        {
           var id = ui.item.value;
           var text = ui.item.label;
           $("#auto").val(name);
           return false;
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
                $("#auto").val(ui.item.label);
                return false;
            }
    });
</script>
```